# zooming of iImageview

Tags: android

i have an imageview

and i have set a bitmap on it:

```
package com.integrated.mpr;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AlternativeShow extends Activity{


    ImageView altiva;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alternativeshow);
        File fa = new File(folder,"bmp1.png");
        Bitmap bmpa = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fa.getAbsolutePath());

        altiva.setImageBitmap(bmpa);
        }
    }
}
```

I want that on touching of the screen on the imageview , the image should be zoomed >>

How can I make it possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a WebView instead. You can load your image like this:

```
webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/image.jpg");
```

Of course you must have your image.jpg in your assets folder.

If you have it in your SD Card...

```
String imageName = "image.jpg";
webview.loadUrl("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/newdir/" + imageName);
```

WebView already has zoom implemented so you don't really need to do anything ;-)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: no actually , in my application i am taking a picture from the camera , saving it to the SD card , and retreiving it from their to the imageview >. can i use wbview in such a case??

Comment: Edited my post to answer your question ;-)

Comment: can u plz specify how to do it from the very basic ... i am a beginner in android apps so plz help.. Wil it automatically zoom in on touching??

Comment: Just create a WebView in your layout, call it exactly as you call your ImageView, and use loadUrl on it. You must pass "file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + the link to your image from SD card.

Your image will have the same zooming and dragging as the android navigator ;-)

Comment: hey i tried , the image gets loaded into the view .. but on clicking it dsnt get zoomed .. i can only scroll.. where is the problem?

Comment: It gets zoomed on double click ;-)